# small error while using firebase setPersistenceEnabled(true)

Tags: android, firebase

I have a `RecyclerView` which shows data from the Firebase. I have used `setPersistenceEnabled(true);` .Everything works fine in online & offline mode also.But the problem is that when i open my app in offline mode and connect it to the internet then `RecyclerView` shows firstly stored data and all online data together,but this problem is gone when i restart the activity.
here is my code in `onCreate()` method

```
    list=new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pdata").child("cdata");
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.festirecycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerAdapter=new DisplayRecyclerAdapter(list,getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter );
    loadRecyclerData();


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootview;
}

private void loadRecyclerData() {

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String da=postSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                list.add(da);


            }
            Collections.reverse(list);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });


}
```

}

Any suggestions??
Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are changing connectivity from Offline to Online its adding the data again in `onDataChanges()` method

The solution is to clear data before adding from `onDataChanges()` like this:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Clear here
            list.clear()
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String da=postSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                list.add(da);


            }
            Collections.reverse(list);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Firebase persistence has anything to do with your issue.

It is more likely that you are handling your `Activity` or `Fragment` lifecycle incorrectly and you are seeing the data in your `RecyclerView` that exists from the last time you ran the app.

You are indiscriminately `Add`ing your objects to the list. You are not first checking whether they already exist within it and then just updating the existing object if it is already there.